# Why is my setTimeout function running twice?

Tags: javascript, loops

so every 5 seconds I expect to receive the message in the console;
but instead, I receive it twice after every 5 seconds.

edit : never mind i'm stupid , i had script linked twice ,

```js
loop();

function loop() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("this runs twice?!");
    loop();
  }, 5000);


}
```

Comment: It doesn't behave that way when I run it.

Comment: You should look at `setInterval` instead. `setTimeout` doesn't work well recursively

Comment: yea just noticed the same thing , must be chrome

Comment: Regarding the edit: it doesn't do that in the Firefox console nor in the Chrome console. I copy and pasted the code posted here. How are you getting that behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function.

Like so:

```js
function loop() {
  console.log("running");
}

setInterval(loop, 5000);
```

Comment: While this is, arguably, a better approach to solving the original problem. It doesn't change the result, so it isn't an answer to the question.